# Is there a way to add memoization for existential types?

Tags: typescript, caching, memoization, type-safety, existential-type

I'm searching for an advice how to cache some data which comes from source with existential type. Let me show you an example of what I mean. This is synthetic example, just to highlight the problem.

Let us say we want to validate something, but also need to preload some data beforehand.

```
type Validator<A> = [dataLoader: () => Promise<A>, check: (input: A) => void];
```

We may have different set of validators and we want to keep them in a single list. In order to do that we hide the `A` param, making it existential:

```
type ExistentialValidator = <R>(run: <A>(validator: Validator<A>) => R) => R

// now we can have this
declare const validators: ExistentialValidator[];
```

And running this list of validators looks like this (type checks nicely):

```
async function runValidation() {
  for (const validator of validators) {
    await validator(([dataLoader, check]) => dataLoader().then((a) => check(a)))
  }
}
```

This is all great and works as expected. But it turned out that the data loaders might be fetching the same info, therefore we would like to somehow identify, that data loaders are `the same` and skip loading the same data more than once.

Initial thoughts were to give the data loader some id

```
type DataLoader<A> = {
  id: string;
  load: () => Promise<A>
}
```

Our `Validator` changes just a tiny bit:

```
type Validator<A> = [dataLoader: DataLoader<A>, check: (input: A) => void];
```

And now when we execute `runValidation` I would like to cache the values returned by `DataLoader`, but fail to see how we can do it without resorting to `any` type

```
async function runValidation() {
  const memo: Map<string, ?>; // some basic cache from DataLoader.id -> to its load result type
  for (const validator of validators) {
    await validator(async ([dataLoader, check]) => {
      let cached = memo.get(dataLoader.id);
      if (!cached) {
        cached = await dataLoader.load();
        memo.set(dataLoader.id, cached);
      }
      return check(cached);
    });
  }
}
```

Any tips how this problem could be approached? Maybe the idea with `id` for each data loader is not that great and there is a better way...

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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)

Comment: Why don't you just `dataLoader`? I think that's the best way to approach cache.
If for some reason you cannot do that, then I'd suggest to use `any`. It's okay as long as you can ensure correctness yourself. You can hide it behind some type safe api.
Also you can try to get rid of existential types using tuples. This way you can have validators for different types at the same tuple.
And you can try to change your data structure to get rid of duplicated loaders: `[Loader, Check[]]`

Comment: Imagine a use case where your validation config is stored somewhere in DB. You retrieve it and you need to build the list of validators to run based on that config. At this point you don't know which validators you end up using, that is why this abstraction is used, just to tell that we can handle some list of validators, without knowing much about them, and they internally are type safe (the reason for existentials in this case)

Comment: I've meant "Why don't you just cache data loader"?

Comment: So you can use your first implementation, but calling same loader multiple times would just return cached data.

Comment: The thing is that data changes somewhat frequently and i need to cache it only in scope of a single `runValidation` - in this case it is a requirement. There is also a concern that validations happen a lot, so data loaders will consume tremendous amount of memory just to keep up with their caches, while this local cache is disposed as soon as the loop is over

Comment: You can have some sort of `invalidateCache` function to run it manually, or make make it time based, with short ttl.

I.e. `const cache = new MyCache(); const dataLoader = cache.wrap(orignalDataLoader)`; and then `runValidate(); cache.clear();`

Comment: One of the biggest problems with caching data loaders is that they are not singletons, so two different instances of the same data loader is possibility therefore making your suggestion hard to bring to life

Comment: I don't know the exact specific of your project, so I can't just give ready to go solution. But I would expect data loaders to use some lower level abstraction, which can be cached. I.e. if you have some DB client and data loader is some specific query in this DB, you can cache DB client.